# How to skip displaying a content item in Orchard CMS?

Tags: datetime, orchardcms

I have a content part that provides a begin timestamp and end timestamp option. These 2 fields are used to define a period of time in which the content item should be displayed.

I now have difficulties to implement a skip approach whereas content items should not be displayed / skipped when the period of time does not span the current time.

Digging in the source code and trying to find an entry point for my approach resulted in the following content handler

```
public class SkipContentHandler : Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.ContentHandler
{
  protected override void BuildDisplayShape(Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.BuildDisplayContext aContext)
  {
    if (...) // my condition to process only content shapes which need to be skipped
    {
      aContext.Shape = null; // return null shape to skip it
    }
  }
}
```

This works but there are several side effects

- I had to alter the source code of `BuildDisplayContext` as the `Shape` is normally read only
- List shape may displayed a wrong pager when it contains content items with my content part because the `Count()` call in `ContainerPartDriver.Display()` is executed before `BuildDisplay()`
- calling the URL of a content item that is skipped results in an exception because `View(null)` is abigious

So, what would be the correct approach here or is there any module in existence that does the job? I couldn't find one.

Comment: You might want to consider to just instead register an 'unpublish' event when the time span expires

Comment: @devqon Yeah i thought about that too. But this would require some sort of background task that runs periodically and this task needs to query all content items to search for the right ones to unpublish. Also, i'm not a fan of unpublishing as it might confuse the user which had clicked the publish button before. I still hope that there is a way to abort the rendering of  a shape safely somehow...

Comment: You might succeed in stop it from rendering, but then you will still have problems with the `Count` as you mentioned. So paging probably fails, and probably more with that

Comment: If you cannot or don't want to alter the queries that return your content, you could create a module that provides fields for the timestamps you mentioned as an attachable part, e.g. _DisplayDurationPart_.
Then I'd create a custom _ContentQuery_ class that inherits from  **DefaultContentQuery** and, for example, alter the `.List()`-Method to filter for that fields before calling `Slice()`.
After that you would need to register the custom _ContentQuery_ class with autofac; check _Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentModule_.

If you're interested in that approach I could create a small demo.

Comment: @Xceno That's an interesting approach. Currently i got the List() stuff working by using projections instead of containers / containable. Therefore i can configure the queries as needed from the admin area. But i would also like to learn more about the DefaultContentQuery approach. Btw: do you have an idea how to cancel rendering a single shape (as this is the only issue left right now)?

Comment: @Xceno Hmm it seems inheriting from **DefaultContentQuery** won't work almost all useful methods are private. I could create a duplicate of the whole file and use this instead.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy I just got stuck with your exact same problem some minutes ago. I'll keep you updated when I've found a definitive solution.
But damn you're right on the DefaultContentQuery; seems like you would have to implement the interface yourself (and just c/p from the standard implementation... meh)

Comment: @Xceno Yep, i'm currently working on a solution to implement IContentQuery.ForPart<TPart>() as this seems the entry point to all queries. I still struggle to to a left join of my content part here to check my fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite complex task. There are several steps needed to achieve a proper *skipping* of display items:

1. **Create the part correctly**

   There are a few pitfalls here as when coming to the task of adding a part view one might utilize Orchards date time editor in connection with the `DateTime` properties. But this brings a heck of a lot of additional issues to the table but these don't really relate to the question.

   If someone is interested in how to use Orchards date time editor then i can post this code too, but for now it would only blow up the code unnecessarly.

   So here we go, the part class...

   ```
   public class ValidityPart : Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentPart<ValidityPartRecord>
   {
     // public
       public System.DateTime? ValidFromUtc 
       { 
         get { return Retrieve(r => r.ValidFromUtc); }
         set { Store(r => r.ValidFromUtc, value); }
       }

       ...

       public System.DateTime? ValidTillUtc 
       { 
         get { return Retrieve(r => r.ValidTillUtc); }
         set { Store(r => r.ValidTillUtc, value); }
       }

       ...

       public bool IsContentItemValid()
       {
         var lUtcNow = System.DateTime.UtcNow;

         return (ValidFromUtc == null || ValidFromUtc.Value <= lUtcNow) && (ValidTillUtc == null || ValidTillUtc.Value >= lUtcNow);
       }

     ...
   }
   ```

   ...and the record class...

   ```
   public class ValidityPartRecord : Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentPartRecord
   {
     // valid from value as UTC to use Orchard convention (see CommonPart table) and to be compatible with projections
     // (date/time tokens work with UTC values, see https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/6963 for a related issue)  
     public virtual System.DateTime? ValidFromUtc { get; set; }

     // valid from value as UTC to use Orchard convention (see CommonPart table) and to be compatible with projections
     // (date/time tokens work with UTC values, see https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/6963 for a related issue)  
     public virtual System.DateTime? ValidTillUtc { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. **Create a customized content query class**

   ```
   public class MyContentQuery : Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentQuery
   { 
     // public
       public ContentQuery(Orchard.ContentManagement.IContentManager aContentManager, 
         Orchard.Data.ITransactionManager aTransactionManager, 
         Orchard.Caching.ICacheManager aCacheManager,
         Orchard.Caching.ISignals aSignals,
         Orchard.Data.IRepository<Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentTypeRecord> aContentTypeRepository,
         Orchard.IWorkContextAccessor aWorkContextAccessor) 
           : base(aContentManager, aTransactionManager, aCacheManager, aSignals, aContentTypeRepository)
       {
         mWorkContextAccessor = aWorkContextAccessor;
       }

       protected override void BeforeExecuteQuery(NHibernate.ICriteria aContentItemVersionCriteria)
       {
         base.BeforeExecuteQuery(aContentItemVersionCriteria);

         // note:
         //  this method will be called each time a query for multiple items is going to be executed (e.g. content items of a container, layers, menus),
         //  this gives us the chance to add a validity criteria

         var lWorkContext = mWorkContextAccessor.GetContext();

         // exclude admin as content items should still be displayed / accessible when invalid as validity needs to be editable
         if (lWorkContext == null || !Orchard.UI.Admin.AdminFilter.IsApplied(lWorkContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext))
         {
           var lUtcNow = System.DateTime.UtcNow;

           // left outer join of ValidityPartRecord table as part is optional (not present on all content types)
           var ValidityPartRecordCriteria = aContentItemVersionCriteria.CreateCriteria(
             "ContentItemRecord.ValidityPartRecord", // string adopted from foreach loops in Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentQuery.WithQueryHints()
             NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin 
           );

           // add validity criterion
           ValidityPartRecordCriteria.Add( 
             NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.And(
               NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Or(
                 NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.IsNull("ValidFromUtc"),
                 NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Le("ValidFromUtc", lUtcNow)
               ),
               NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Or(
                 NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.IsNull("ValidTillUtc"),
                 NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Ge("ValidTillUtc", lUtcNow)
               )
             )
           );
         }
       }

     // private
       Orchard.IWorkContextAccessor mWorkContextAccessor;
   }
   ```

   This essentially adds a left join of the validity part fields to the SQL query (content query) and extends the `WHERE` statement with the validity condition.

   Please note that this step is only possible with the solution described the following issue: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/6978
3. **Register the content query class**

   ```
   public class ContentModule : Autofac.Module
   {
     protected override void Load(Autofac.ContainerBuilder aBuilder)
     {
       aBuilder.RegisterType<MyContentQuery>().As<Orchard.ContentManagement.IContentQuery>().InstancePerDependency();
     }
   }
   ```
4. **Create a customized content manager**

   ```
   public class ContentManager : Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager
   {
     // public
       public ContentManager(
         Autofac.IComponentContext aContext,
         Orchard.Data.IRepository<Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentTypeRecord> aContentTypeRepository,
         Orchard.Data.IRepository<Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentItemRecord> aContentItemRepository,
         Orchard.Data.IRepository<Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentItemVersionRecord> aContentItemVersionRepository,
         Orchard.ContentManagement.MetaData.IContentDefinitionManager aContentDefinitionManager,
         Orchard.Caching.ICacheManager aCacheManager,
         System.Func<Orchard.ContentManagement.IContentManagerSession> aContentManagerSession,
         System.Lazy<Orchard.ContentManagement.IContentDisplay> aContentDisplay,
         System.Lazy<Orchard.Data.ITransactionManager> aTransactionManager,
         System.Lazy<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.IContentHandler>> aHandlers,
         System.Lazy<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Orchard.ContentManagement.IIdentityResolverSelector>> aIdentityResolverSelectors,
         System.Lazy<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Orchard.Data.Providers.ISqlStatementProvider>> aSqlStatementProviders,
         Orchard.Environment.Configuration.ShellSettings aShellSettings,
         Orchard.Caching.ISignals aSignals,
         Orchard.IWorkContextAccessor aWorkContextAccessor)
           : base(aContext, aContentTypeRepository, aContentItemRepository, aContentItemVersionRepository, aContentDefinitionManager, aCacheManager, aContentManagerSession,
               aContentDisplay, aTransactionManager, aHandlers, aIdentityResolverSelectors, aSqlStatementProviders, aShellSettings, aSignals)
       {
         mWorkContextAccessor = aWorkContextAccessor;
       }

       public override ContentItem Get(int aId, Orchard.ContentManagement.VersionOptions aOptions, Orchard.ContentManagement.QueryHints aHints)
       {
         var lResult = base.Get(aId, aOptions, aHints);

         if (lResult != null)
         {
           // note:
           //  the validity check is done here (after the query has been executed!) as changing base.GetManyImplementation() to 
           //  apply the validity critera directly to the query (like in ContentQuery) will not work due to a second attempt to retrieve the
           //  content item from IRepository<> (see base.GetManyImplementation(), comment "check in memory") when the query
           //  returns no data (and the query should not return data when the validity critera is false)
           //
           // http://stackoverflow.com/q/37841249/3936440

           var lWorkContext = mWorkContextAccessor.GetContext();

           // exclude admin as content items should still be displayed / accessible when invalid as validity needs to be editable
           if (lWorkContext == null || !Orchard.UI.Admin.AdminFilter.IsApplied(lWorkContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext))
           {
             var lValidityPart = lResult.As<ValidityPart>();
             if (lValidityPart != null)
             {
               if (lValidityPart.IsContentItemValid())
               {
                 // content item is valid
               }
               else
               {
                 // content item is not valid, return null (adopted from base.Get())

                 lResult = null;
               }
             }
           }
         }

         return lResult;
       }

     // private
       Orchard.IWorkContextAccessor mWorkContextAccessor;
   }
   ```

Steps 2-4 are needed when having content items whereas the content type has a `Container` and `Containable` part or even content items which are processed / displayed separately. Here you normally cannot customize the content query that is executed behind the scenes.

Steps 2-4 are *not* needed if you use the Projection module. But again, this brings a few other issues to the table as reported in this issue: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/6979