# How to extend OrchardCMS to show/hide navigation and content from intranet vs internet users

Tags: orchardcms

I have certain pages that I want accessible only to users that are accessing the site from within a given IP range.   For all other users, these pages should be inaccessible, and their respective links not visible in the menu/navigation.

I'm new to OrchardCMS, can someone provide some general guidance and point me in the right direction?

Comment: Checkout [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879500/how-to-limit-page-access-only-to-localhost)

Comment: devqon, I know how to do this in dot.net, it's not a matter of syntax.  The question is how do I extend orchardCMS to result in this behavior.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There two aspects to answer your question.

**1. To check access to orchard content items and menu item relative to it:**

To achieve this, you can implement new `IAuthorizationServiceEventHandler` to replace the default roles based authorization service, the best sample for you is `ContentMenuItemAuthorizationEventHandler` which you can find under `Orchard.ContentPicker` module, I included a sample code to explain the usage of this handler:

```cs
public class CustomAuthorizationEventHandler : 
    IAuthorizationServiceEventHandler{

    public ContentMenuItemAuthorizationEventHandler() {
    }

    public void Checking(CheckAccessContext context) { }
    public void Adjust(CheckAccessContext context) {
        //Here you can put your business to grant user or not
        context.Granted = true; //Roles service will look to this value to grant access to the user 
        context.Adjusted = true;
    }

    public void Complete(CheckAccessContext context) {}
}
```

**2. To check access to some actions.**

To achieve this, you can implement new `IAuthorizationFilter` to check access to some actions in your system:

```cs
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter : FilterProvider, IAuthorizationFilter {
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
        if (!Granted) {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions mentioned by @mdameer are ok, but you will run into difficulties when using containers, lists, projections and stuff.

I had a similar task but with date time ranges. See my question and answer to the task to get an idea how to tackle this via a custom part:

[How to skip displaying a content item in Orchard CMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684524/how-to-skip-displaying-a-content-item-in-orchard-cms)