# Can I efficiently query generic fields without resorting to HQL?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I find myself doing a lot of queries to fetch just the first couple of items of a big set, e.g. to show the three most recent news articles or blog posts on the homepage of a website.

As long as this query only involves predefined or custom Parts, I can do something like this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<ContentItem> GetTopArticles(int amount)
{
    var cultureRecord = _cultureManager.GetCultureByName(_orchardServices.WorkContext.CurrentCulture);

    var articles = _orchardServices.ContentManager.Query().ForType("Article")
        .Where<LocalizationPartRecord>(lpr => lpr.CultureId == cultureRecord.Id)
        .OrderBy<CommonPartRecord>(cpr => cpr.PublishedUtc)
        .Slice(0, amount);

    return articles;
}
```

I'm assuming this will more or less be the same as a `SELECT TOP [amount] ...` in SQL and will have good performance on a large number of records.

However, sometimes I use Migrations or Import to create Content Types from an external source and want to conditionally check a field from the generic Part. In this case I don't have a Part or PartRecord class that I can pass as a parameter to the ContentQuery methods and if I want to do a conditional check on any of the fields I currently do something like this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<ContentItem> GetTopArticles(int amount)
{
    var articles = _orchardServices.ContentManager.Query().ForType("Article")
        .OrderBy<CommonPartRecord>(cpr => cpr.PublishedUtc)
        .List()
        .Where(a => a.Content.Article.IsFeatured.Value == true)
        .Take(amount);

    return articles;
}
```

This is really wasteful and causes large overhead on big sets but I really, **REALLY**, do not want to delve into the database to figure out Orchard's inner workings and construct long and complex HQL queries every time I want to do something like this.

### Is there any way to rewrite the second query with IContentQuery methods without incurring a large performance hit?

Comment: You may not want to, but HQL is the way to go. ContentManager is incapable of doing anything efficiently but the most basic queries.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy What about a string search on the Data field in the ContentItemVersionRecord? I know I shouldn't be this averse to learning HQL but technically that would be faster than going over large sets in memory right?

Comment: Well, that would be even worse: string searches perform notoriously badly, and you'd have to rely on the serialization format for fields, and more generally on an implementation detail. That's extremely brittle.

Comment: You could provide a customized content query / content manager class. I had an similar issue but without generic fields. Perhaps you can use my solution one way or the other: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38369053/3936440

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar (being able to query model data with a dynamic name). Sadly, I haven't found anything that makes it easy.

The method I've found that works is to do plain SQL queries against the database. Check out [this module](https://bitbucket.org/bleroy/orchardpo/src/87045c32cbffc7d731e0c1fd3db2a73827c54d47/Services/LocalizationService.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) for syntax on that if you do later find yourself willing to delve into the database.